# Why spring-data-rest doesn't include _links on inlined resources when using projections?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Suppose we have resource `Appointment` with an association `client` that point to a `Client` resource.

Now if we inline `client` with `appointment` we don't get `_links` on `client` anymore. There is a link for client in `appointment._links` but this is relative to appointment like `http://localhost/appointment/1/client` instead of directly pointing to client resource like `http://localhost/clients/123`

Is there a way to include the `_links` on the `appointment.client` itself?